# Access another DB in the service provider

Tags: php, laravel, service-provider

I am new to service providers in Laravel so I am a little bit confused.

I am developing a application that uses some kind of *service provider*. The service provider is basically making queries against another DB. The settings for that other DB are in the env file and also in the `config\database` I am using another mysql connection (**mysql2**).

My question is how to send the mysql2 to the service provider so the class that is registering to use it?

Thank you for all your help

Comment: You need to use `Illuminate\Database\DatabaseManager` in your service provider page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you need to use *DatabaseManager* as below:

```
use Illuminate\Database\DatabaseManager;
use DB;
```

Then you need to use the connection you want to use as below:

```
DB::connection('mysql2')->table('test_table')->get();
```

Hope, it will help you.
Thanks